# how to hash user password in symfony 5.2.6 when using security.yaml and make:user command

Tags: php, symfony, symfony5, password-hash

**Versions I Used**:
using (symfony 5.2.6) with (api-platform 2.7.0)  alongside (php 8.0.3) and (postgres 13)

**Description**
used maker bundle to generate a User Entity and configured the security.yaml to encode passwords already tried auto and bcrypt or even argon2i non of them seems to work and hash the passwords

**Possible Solution**
as the symfony documentation describes it should automatically encode passwords if we are using security bundle and implementing UserInterface but this one seems like a bug cause i have tried many things nothing works . maybe using UserPasswordEncoderInterface but this one should not be used when User class is implementing UserInterface anyway i hope someone check this and tell me i'm wrong otherwise seems like a bug.

security.yaml:

```yaml
security:
    encoders:
        App\Entity\User:
            algorithm: bcrypt

    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers
    providers:
        # used to reload user from session & other features (e.g. switch_user)
        app_user_provider:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\User
                property: username
    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            anonymous: true
            lazy: true
            provider: app_user_provider

            # activate different ways to authenticate
            # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#firewalls-authentication

            # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/impersonating_user.html
            # switch_user: true

    # Easy way to control access for large sections of your site
    # Note: Only the *first* access control that matches will be used
    access_control:
        # - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
        # - { path: ^/profile, roles: ROLE_USER }

        # or require ROLE_ADMIN or IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY for /admin*
        # - { path: '^/admin', roles: [IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY, ROLE_ADMIN] }

        # the 'path' value can be any valid regular expression
        # (this one will match URLs like /api/post/7298 and /api/comment/528491)
        # - { path: ^/api/(post|comment)/\d+$, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

User.php:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\UserRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use App\Entity\Trait\HasDateTime;
use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * @ApiResource
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=UserRepository::class)
 * @ORM\Table(name="`user`")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class User implements UserInterface
{
    use HasDateTime;
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=180, unique=true)
     */
    #[Assert\NotBlank]
    #[Assert\Email]
    private $email;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=180, unique=true)
     */
    #[Assert\NotBlank]
    private $username;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="json")
     */
    private $roles = [];

    /**
     * @var string The hashed password
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    #[Assert\NotBlank]
    private $password;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getEmail(): string
    {
        return (string) $this->email;
    }

    public function setEmail(string $email): self
    {
        $this->email = $email;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * A visual identifier that represents this user.
     *
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function getUsername(): string
    {
        return (string) $this->username;
    }

    public function setUsername(string $username): self
    {
        $this->username = $username;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function getRoles(): array
    {
        $roles = $this->roles;
        // guarantee every user at least has ROLE_USER
        $roles[] = 'ROLE_USER';

        return array_unique($roles);
    }

    public function setRoles(array $roles): self
    {
        $this->roles = $roles;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function getPassword(): string
    {
        return (string) $this->password;
    }

    public function setPassword(string $password): self
    {
        $this->password = $password;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Returning a salt is only needed, if you are not using a modern
     * hashing algorithm (e.g. bcrypt or sodium) in your security.yaml.
     *
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function getSalt(): ?string
    {
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function eraseCredentials()
    {
        // If you store any temporary, sensitive data on the user, clear it here
        // $this->plainPassword = null;
    }
}
```

tried to save data in the database each time it saved passwords as plaintext.

also tried to remove the trait class thought it might conflict some how which seems strange(i know) (but i just gave it a try) it was not hashing passwords even after removing the trait. what am i doing wrong or missing here?
thanks in advance

Comment: You will probably need to [implement your own DataPersister or decorate an existing one](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/data-persisters/#decorating-the-built-in-data-persisters). This persister should then handle the password hashing similarly to how you would do it [in the docs security section 2c](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#c-encoding-passwords)

Comment: It is up to you to actually encode the password.  The security.yaml stuff tells the system how to check the password.  Run the command 'bin/console make:registration-form' and check the generated controller to see the required code.

Comment: @dbrumann you are right i had to use DataPersister, thanks for the answer

Answer (score 1):

here is the solution:

i had to create a class that implements DataPersister then in there we have to encode the password . here is the code:

```php
<?php

namespace App\DataPersister;

use App\Entity\User;
use ApiPlatform\Core\DataPersister;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use ApiPlatform\Core\DataPersister\DataPersisterInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\UserPasswordEncoderInterface;

class UserDataPersister implements DataPersisterInterface
{
    public function __construct(private EntityManagerInterface $entityManager, private UserPasswordEncoderInterface $userPasswordEncoderInterface)
    {
        
    }

    /**
     * Is the data supported by the persister?
     */
    public function supports($data): bool
    {
        return $data instanceof User;
    }

    /**
     * @param User $data
     * @return object|void Void will not be supported in API Platform 3, an object should always be returned
     */
    public function persist($data)
    {
        if ($data->getPassword()) {
            $data->setPassword(
                $this->userPasswordEncoderInterface->encodePassword($data, $data->getPassword())
            );
        }
        $this->entityManager->persist($data);
        $this->entityManager->flush();
    }

    /**
     * Removes the data.
     */
    public function remove($data)
    {
        $this->entityManager->remove($data);
        $this->entityManager->flush();
    }
}
```