Subscribers don't get called in API Platform 3.2 / Symfony6.4
I made a subscriber to hash a password when a user is created with a POST api call:
readonly class PasswordHashSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    public function __construct(private UserPasswordHasherInterface $userPasswordHasher)
    {
    }
    
    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public static function getSubscribedEvents(): array
    {
        return [
             KernelEvents::VIEW => ['hashPassword', EventPriorities::PRE_WRITE
            ],
        ];
    }

    public function hashPassword(ViewEvent $event): void
    {
        $user = $event->getControllerResult();
        $method = $event->getRequest()->getMethod();

        if (!$user instanceof User || Request::METHOD_POST !== $method) {
            return;
        }

        $user->setPassword($this->userPasswordHasher->hashPassword($user, $user->getPassword()));
    }
}

the user gets created and persisted, but the password is "as submitted" and doesn't get hashed. I also placed some logger and found out the subscriber is not called at all.
The subscriber seems configured correctly:
bin/console debug:container PasswordHashSubscriber                                    

Information for Service "App\EventSubscriber\PasswordHashSubscriber"
====================================================================

 ---------------- -------------------------------------------- 
  Option           Value                                       
 ---------------- -------------------------------------------- 
  Service ID       App\EventSubscriber\PasswordHashSubscriber  
  Class            App\EventSubscriber\PasswordHashSubscriber  
  Tags             kernel.event_subscriber                     
  Public           no                                          
  Synthetic        no                                          
  Lazy             no                                          
  Shared           yes                                         
  Abstract         no                                          
  Autowired        yes                                         
  Autoconfigured   yes                                         
  Usages           debug.event_dispatcher                      
 ---------------- -------------------------------------------- 


bin/console debug:event-dispatcher

 ------- ----------------------------------------------------------------------------- ---------- 
  Order   Callable                                                                      Priority  
 ------- ----------------------------------------------------------------------------- ---------- 
  #1      App\EventSubscriber\PasswordHashSubscriber::hashPassword()                    33        
  #2      Symfony\Bridge\Twig\EventListener\TemplateAttributeListener::onKernelView()   -128      
 ------- ----------------------------------------------------------------------------- ---------- 


I already tried event_listeners_backward_compatibility_layer: true but no luck

Out of curiosity: why do you use a listener on KernelEvents::VIEW for this, and not one for Doctrine's prePersist or preUpdate?

I always have done like this, do you think the issue is KernelEvents::VIEW? can you show me an alternative or point me to some doc please?

actually, I just tried. It looks like the subscriber never gets called.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67056620/how-to-hash-user-password-in-symfony-5-2-6-when-using-security-yaml-and-makeuse could help

Did you try this way - https://api-platform.com/docs/core/user/

@DmitryLeiko yes that's exactly how I ended up to do it. However I am still concerned I cannot listen to KernelEvents::VIEW in a subscriber.

Why are you concerned about this? This sounds like a pretty hacky way to set the password - when you add some kind of admin backend, you would need a different way. If you use any frontend where the user could edit the password on its own, you would need a different way. Why not use a Doctrine listener that would cover all of these situations?
